# Disable WCF instruction page

Tags: wcf

Ah! I've done this before, just can't recall.  How do you disable this page when you land on the WCF .svc page?  So that it just displays a blank page?

[image: WCF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [ServiceDebugBehavior.HttpHelpPageEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.httphelppageenabled.aspx) to false

Example:

```
<services>
  <service 
    name="Microsoft.WCF.Documentation.SampleService"
    behaviorConfiguration="metadataAndDebug">
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataAndDebug">
      <serviceDebug 
        httpHelpPageEnabled="false" 
      />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```